# Converting a matrix of strings containing scientific notation numbers into a single line array

Tags: c

I have a matrix of numbers in a text file that look like this :

0.0000e+00  100.00E-15  -100.00E-15
2.5000e-02  100.00E-15  -150.00E-15
5.0000e-02  150.00E-15  -100.00E-15
7.5000e-02  100.00E-15  -100.00E-15
1.0000e-01  100.00E-15  -100.00E-15
1.2500e-01  100.00E-15  -100.00E-15
1.5000e-01  150.00E-15  -100.00E-15
1.7500e-01  150.00E-15  -100.00E-15
2.0000e-01  150.00E-15  -100.00E-15
2.2500e-01  200.00E-15  -100.00E-15
2.5000e-01  150.00E-15  -100.00E-15
2.7500e-01  200.00E-15  -150.00E-15

And so on.

I can scan them in using fgets to make, effectively, a very long string of numbers.  The problem I'm facing is that the size of the matrix is of variable length, and I'm relatively new to programming, so my only knowledge of how to deal with this is by using sscanf and atof. However, when I try to store the value converted by atof into an array, it gives strange behaviour (such as "remembering" the last atof conversion, or just entering 0.)

```
char * strArr[numData][1000];
double varArr[numData];  /* number of data values in the matrix, in this case, 36 */
int i = 0;
int j = 0;

/* The actual data is preceded by a header, hence 8 */
/* dataArr is the lines of the text file that I retrieved using fgets */
/* I'm attempting to store each "string" in a string array, and then convert them to floats using the second loop */

for (i = 8; i < lineCount; i++)
{
    sscanf(dataArr[i], "%s %s %s", strArr[j], strArr[j+1], strArr[j+2]);
    j = j + 3;
}

for (i = 0; i < numData; i++);
{
    varArr[i] = atof(strArr[i]);
}
```

The final part gives me wrong value errors for varArr[i].  I'm honestly a little fried at this point.

strArr[i] is a correct floating point number as a string and  atof(strArr[i]) is a correct floating point number, yet when I try store atof(strArr[i]) into varArr[i] (which is an array of floating point numbers) I get 0.000000e+000.  Did I miss something?

For example

```
strArr[1] returns 100.00E-15
atof(strArr[1]) returns 100.00E-15
varArr[1] = atof(strArr[1]) returns 0.000000e+000
```

EDIT 2:  SOLVED

Turns out I needed to put the atof function inside the first loop, eg:

```
for (i = 8; i < lineCount; i++)
    {
        sscanf(dataArr[i], "%s %s %s", strArr[j], strArr[j+1], strArr[j+2]);
        varArr[j] = atof(strArr[j]);
        varArr[j+1] = atof(strArr[j+1]);
        varArr[j+2] = atof(strArr[j+2]);
        j = j + 3;
    }
```

I have no idea why, but it works so I'm happy.

Comment: Why not just scanf 3 at a time for each line?

Comment: @stark because the posted example `sscanf(str, %s %s %s %s %s ....., f)` shows there may be more than 3 values per line.

Comment: @user3121023 so how will you know how many values per line by using `fscanf` which knows nothing about lines?

Comment: (1). Read lines using `fgets`.  (2) Split each line into "words" using `strtok` or the like.  (3) Convert "words" to floating-point using either `atof` or `strtod`.  (4) Store floating-point numbers into your array.  (5) If your array isn't big enough, use `realloc` to make it bigger.  (This last bit assume you initially used `malloc`.)

Comment: @user3121023 you missed the posted example `sscanf(str, %s %s %s %s %s ....., f)` which shows there may be more than 3 values per line.

Comment: @user3121023 `fgets` reads up the the next newline, or buffer size limit. It doesn't make anything. It seems clear that the input may contain any number of items, and any number of lines. OP says **size of the matrix is of variable length**.

Comment: Clarification: Theres only 3 pieces of data.  I used the %s %s %s %s %s.... as a means of expressing my inability to parse 3 lines of string data, and then store them into an array.

Comment: What is `numData` defined as and initialized to?

Comment: numData is defined as an integer and its initialized to the number of lines of data * 3.  So for a matrix of 3 x 12 the size is 36.

Comment: You've allocated a series of 1000 pointers, but you've not made any of them point anywhere useful.  You must provide the memory to read the strings into!

Comment: So, how hard would it have been to write `int numData = 15;` at the top of your code, possibly with a comment explaining that it is calculated in the full program.

Comment: I thought I needed to allocate space for the 2d array.  EDIT: Noticed that this code was missing the 2d array.  I updated it.

Comment: "*I'm relatively new to programming*" Do you have to do this in C? Perhaps a more forgiving language like Ruby or Python would be a better place to start.

Comment: Yeah, it has to be C unfortunatly.

Comment: Please clarify "gives me errors". Are there compilation errors? If so, please quote them, and mark which line of your code they refer to. Runtime errors? Please describe which errors you see; quote messages or otherwise describe the behavior. Or maybe by "errors" you mean wrong output? If so, describe the correct output you want, and the incorrect output you get.

Comment: Added the "errors".  Its wrong output errors, not compilation.  I've further clarified my post.

Answer (score 1):

Working with strings correctly in C usually involves dynamic allocation and careful thought about when and what to allocate and free. This is tricky to get right, and you really want to make the strings as few as possible.

If you don't want to handle unusually long input lines (seems your case), you can make do with only one string buffer, which only holds the string temporarily, until the following string replaces it:

```
char strArr[1000];
```

Use `fgets` to fill it. Then use `sscanf` to get numbers from it:

```
sscanf(strArr, "%f %f %f", &varArr[j], &varArr[j+1], &varArr[j+2]);
```

Note: there is no need to extract 3 strings from one string, and convert each string individually to `float`. Extracting the 3 floats immediately, like in the code above, eliminates the extra strings and their memory management.